# stochastic exponential

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I was able to show the following:

$X$ a semimartingale, $X_0=0$ then the SDE

$$ dZ_t=Z_tdX_t$$

with $ Z_0=1$ has the unique solution $Z_t:=\exp{(X_t-\frac{1}{2}\langle X\rangle_t)}$.

I was able to show that this is indeed the a solution. However I got stuck at uniqueness. What I did so far: Suppose there are two solution, $Z,Z^{'}$. Apply Itô to $f(x,y):=\frac{x}{y}$ and with the $\mathbb{R}^2$ semimartingale $(Z,Z^{'})$. After some calculations, I'm at the point:

$$df(Z_t,Z^{'}_t)=\frac{Z^{'}_t}{Z^3_t}d\langle Z\rangle_t -\frac{1}{Z^2_t}d\langle Z,Z^{'}\rangle_t$$

The last two term should be equal, then uniqueness follows. Now why is this, i.e. why is it true that

$$d\langle Z\rangle_t = (Z_t)^2d\langle X\rangle_t$$

and

$$ d\langle Z,Z^{'} \rangle_t = Z^{'}Zd\langle X\rangle_t$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found this equation in lecture notes, without a comment why they are true.(also in the example of stochastic exponential).

Comment: Speaking only for continuous martingales, if $dZ_t = \sigma_t dX_t$ then the quadratic variation/compensator of $Z_t$ is $\int \sigma_t^2 d[X_t,X_t]$.  If you are working from the def $Z^2 - [Z_t,Z_t]$ should be a martingale it is almost Ito's isometry, and if you are working directly from def of quadratic variation, start with step functions, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nobody showed an interest in this since more than ten years. The two equations OP got stuck at are total standard in the theory of stochastic integration.